# how to upload data from a large file into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i have a file with three columns mobile number,company name and Status with millions of records.i have already read the data from the file and stored the data from each column in their respective arrays.I would have used loadInfile mysql but the issue is instead of company names i want to store there company_ids which are stored in my mysql table.So basically what i want to do replace company names with their company_ids but the problem is simple select statements will take so much time because the record is in millions.Kindly suggest me a feasible approach thankx.just for the sake of understanding i am giving a code below

```
$company_names_arr=array('ABC','Def','Ghi',.......);

foreach($company_names_arr as $arr)
 {
  $this->db->select('company_id');
  $this->db->from('companies_info');
  $this->db->where('company_name',$arr);
  $q=$this->db->get();
  $res=$q->result();
  $company_ids_arr[]=$res;
 }
```

i know above written code is not a feasible approach to achieve what i want to achieve so please suggest me a better way thankx

Answer (score 0):

Forget inserting so much data line by line, it will be very slow as you have already found out.

Use `load data infile` to load the text file as is to a staging table. The staging table should have an index on the company name column. Then use [insert ... select ...](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html) with a join to get the company id inserted into the final table.

Comment: to achieve this i have to make another table

Comment: which will be used to store the load in file data